# Working with an array of strings in C

Tags: c

I am trying to use the following code to read a sentence(string) and then display the words of the sentence. It doesn't display as it should. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 100

int main()
{
    char s[N];
    char words[N][N];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    printf("s=");
    gets(s);
    while ((i<strlen(s)) && (s[i]!='.'))
    {
        while (s[i]!= ' ')
        {
            sprintf(words[j],"%c", s[i]);
            i++;
        }
        j++; i++;
    }
    for (i=0;i<j;i++) printf("%s ", words[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usually we use debugger in these cases...

Comment: Don't make us guess at what is wrong. Describe the input, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: `sprintf(words[j],"%c", s[i])` means neither more nor less than `words[j][0]=s[i]; words[j][1]=0`. You're never assigning anywhere else than to the first position of each word.

Answer (score 0):

Your while-loop logic is wrong; it should be:

```
int  k = 0;
while (s[i] != ' ')
    words[j][k++] = s[i++];
words[j][k] = '\0';
```

Also, you never write a terminating null character (`'\0'`) to `words[]`, so the `printf()` call will fail.

Comment: no need to a terminating null character (`'\0'`) because he use `sprintf()` and the `sprintf()` function terminate string buffers with (`'\0'`)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you should get the idea:

```
int size = strlen(s);
int start = 0;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (s[i] == ' ') {
        char* word = malloc((i-start)*size(char)+1); // alloc memory for a word
        strcpy(word, s+size(char)*i, i-start); // copy only the selected word
        word[i-start+1] = '\0'; // add '\0' at the end of string
        printf("%s\n", word);
        start = i + 1; // set new start index value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 100

int main()
{
    char s[N];
    char words[N][N] = {0} ; /* this initial your array to 0 */
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    printf("s=");
    gets(s);
    while ((i<strlen(s)) && (s[i]!='.'))
    {
        while (s[i]!= ' ')
        {
            sprintf(words[j]+strlen(words[j]),"%c", s[i]); /* this will concat chars in words[j] */
            i++;
        }
        j++; i++;
    }
    for (i=0;i<j;i++) printf("%s ", words[i]);
    return 0;
}
```